# how to manage laravel 4 route before events

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this code in my routes.php

```
Route::group(["before" => "guest"], function()
{
Route::any("/", [
"as" => "user/login",
"uses" => "UserController@loginAction"
]);
Route::any("/login", [
"as" => "login",
"uses" => "UserController@loginAction"
]);
Route::any("/request", [
"as" => "user/request",
"uses" => "UserController@requestAction"
]);
Route::any("/reset", [
"as" => "user/reset",
"uses" => "UserController@resetAction"
]);
});
Route::group(["before" => "auth"], function()
{
Route::any("/dashboard", [
"as" => "user/dashboard",
"uses" => "UserController@dashboardAction"
]);
Route::any("/users", [
"as" => "users",
"uses" => "UsersController@indexAction"
]);
Route::any("/calculations", [
"as" => "calculations",
"uses" => "CalculationsController@indexAction"
]);
Route::any("/help", [
"as" => "help",
"uses" => "GeneralController@helpAction"
]);
Route::any("/contact-us", [
"as" => "contact-us",
"uses" => "GeneralController@contactUsAction"
]);
Route::any("/settings", [
"as" => "user/settings",
"uses" => "SettingsController@indexAction"
]);
Route::any("/logout", [
"as" => "user/logout",
"uses" => "UserController@logoutAction"
]);
});
```

I want to redirect authenticated uses trying to access guest pages to another page, how i can I do it ? I am using Laravel 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `auth` filter you already reference in the group in your `filters.php` with something like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    // Auth::guest() returns true if user is not logged in:
    if (Auth::guest())  
    {
        return Redirect::action('UserController@loginAction');
    }
});
```

I'm taking a guess here that `UserController@loginAction` points at your login page.. :)

More here in the Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by customizing the filters.php file in same folder.